# npm version doesn't pickup user/email from config in GitHub actions

Tags: npm, github-actions

I have the following in my workflow yaml file:

```yaml
    - name: Bump Version
      id: version
      run: echo "version=$(npm version patch)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

if I don't also have the following, git throws an error:

```yaml
    env:
      GIT_AUTHOR_NAME: github-actions[bot]
      GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL: 41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com
      GIT_COMMITTER_NAME: github-actions[bot]
      GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL: 41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com
```

example error:

```
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command /usr/bin/git --no-replace-objects commit -m 0.0.6
npm ERR! Committer identity unknown
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! *** Please tell me who you are.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
npm ERR!   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! to set your account's default identity.
npm ERR! Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: empty ident name (for <runner@fv-az1016-3.pv3vitign2bulj5h5vrau5ekvd.cx.internal.cloudapp.net>) not allowed

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-12-20T05_16_53_302Z-debug-0.log
```

However running `git commit` outside npm, does not cause this error, because github actions sets these values for you (or maybe it's the checkout action, but it IS set). How can I get npm to not ignore/filter out the values set by github when calling git?